# Выборка из двух таблиц

Tags: mysql

Есть таблицы

> `products
> id | name | group_id | visibility
> products_copy
> id | product_id | group_id`

Как составить запрос на выборку данных из обоих таблиц по критерию `group_id`.

Пример данных при выборке для group_id 31:

products

1 | вилка | 31 | 1

2 | ножег | 31 | 1

3 | ложко | 32 | 1

products_copy

1 | 3 | 31

В итоге выборки нужно получить:

1 | вилка

2 | ножег

3 | ложко

Comment: В общем выборка бесполезная, так как чтобы получить данные, тут join не нужен

Comment: Как тогда их выбирать?

Comment: Вероятней всего это ты себе придумал тренировочное задание, но придумал бы чтото правильнее... Чем эта каша

Comment: Если правильно понял задачу, то тут надо использовать union. только почему такие разные таблицы совсем непонятно. можно пример данных и результат, который нужно получить?

Comment: Есть товар который привязян к определенной группе (products . group_id), но его также нужно показать и в других категориях где его физически нет, для это используется таблица products_copy. Обновил вопрос.

Comment: Как? Как при выборке из первой таблице, где групИд =31, может быть ложка из 32 группы?

Comment: У тебя связи в таблицах абсолютно не правильные, продуктИд это вневний ключ для ид из таблици 1, и там не надо дублировать ид группы

Comment: Через таблицу products_copy, там есть эта ложка с групИд=31

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Требуемый запрос:

```
SELECT id, name
FROM products
WHERE 
  group_id=31 and visibility
UNION 
SELECT pc.id, p.name
FROM products_copy pc
JOIN products p ON pc.product_id = p.id and p.visibility
WHERE pc.group_id = 31
```

Проблема у вас в структуре. Множественное (многие ко многим) подчинение делают через развязочную таблицу.  Т.е. должна быть таблица `products(id,name,visibility)`, таблица `groups(id,name)` и развязочная между ними `product_groups(product_id,group_id)`. В этом случае выборки строятся проще. В частности *"получить все продукты в категории"* и *"получить все категории, в которые входит продукт"* становится одинаково просто и естественно.

Comment: Большое спасибо, всё работает. Про хранения привяки в отдельной таблице я в курсе, сам всегда так делаю когда один товар необходимо хранить в нескольких группач, однако сейчас нужен вот такой велосипед :)

Comment: Бывает ) Да, если будет гарантия от дублей в первой части запроса и во второй, то можно вместо union писать union all, это слегка ускорит запрос, правда на небольших выборках несущественно.

Comment: Там таблицы до 30к записей, работает быстро пока, а вот за уникальность сказать сложно )) поэтому пусть медленне, но зато точно правильно :)

Answer (score 0):

Укажи в селекте строки которые надо вывести из 2й таблицы

Comment: Это не совсем то.
В первой таблице (products) 20 товаров с группой 31, а во второй таблице (products_copy) 12 товаров с группой 31. Т.е. в результате выборки их должно быть 32, а у меня только 20 выбирается. В таблице products_copy у меня только id товара и группы, мне нужно чтобы по критерию группа были выбраны эти 12 товаров, а данные подробные по ним из использованя из таблицы products. Вот.

Comment: Всеравно ты их не поместишь в один столбец таблици, попробуй что то типа, select t1./*, t2.* from table as t1, table2 as t2 where твои условия...

Comment: Тода как одна ложка может быть в разных группах?

Comment: В принятом ответ, ответ на этот коммент :)

Answer (score 0):

```
(SELECT `id`, `name`, `group_id` FROM `products` WHERE `id`="что-то") UNION (SELECT `id`, `product_id`, `group_id` FROM `products_copy` WHERE `id`="что-то");
```

если правильно понял тз, то делается так

Comment: Так это идеальнай выборка для всего ) даже понимать не надо нечего, все по формуле - выборка union выборка еще какаето union еще чето...

Comment: ну хорошо хоть таблицы и поля из моего поста, а могло бы быть SELECT 'какой-то id', 'еще чё нить'  и т.д. 
Бгг